# Why does Software Center report qt4 as unmet dependency, when I already have qt5 installed?

Tags: dependencies, qt, qt5

I installed `qtspim` which requires `qt4` to be installed. As I already have `qt5` installed on my system, `qtspim` is working fine.

However, Software Center reports dependency error. When I run `apt-get check` it gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qtspim : Depends: qt4-dev-tools (>= 4.7) but it is not installed
      Depends: qt4-doc (>= 4.7) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I don't want to install qt4 as i already have the latest version installed.

Answer (score 4):

## No

you have to install qt4 libs for running qt4 programs, qt5 is not 100% backward compatable with qt4

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide a reference about this.

Comment: @Anwar: The name of the shared libraries are different and therefore an application that links to the Qt4 libraries will run only if the Qt4 libraries are present.